How to reuse string from library with Flutter
When working with Android (Kotlin) there are many strings that are used many times, I package them in a library (carefully translated into many different languages).
When I need to use it, just add that library and use is very easy.
With Flutter how can I do that?
P/s: I need to find a solution combined with GetX

check easy_localization package, it allows you to declare your translations in json files matching the languages you want like en.json
, it.json...
then it provides you with methods to show each string by its JSON key, like:
final text = Text(("my_string_key".tr());

Which will show the appropriate value on the language which the app is configured to.

If I use GetX do you have any other solution?

You can access the official flutter documentation about internationalising your flutter application here:
i18n | Flutter.
As already mentioned, there is other packages that can do the work, it depends on your needs.

If I use GetX do you have any other solution?

Sorry I don't understand how GetX is linked to your issue

You can create a package for translations with flutter create -t package [package_name] and store translated strings there.
The package can be imported via path or git repository, see the docs for details.
Also here is a great piece on implementing l10n in Flutter in a robust way.

If I use GetX do you have any other solution?

The linked solution is universal
